# How To Log Into Web Service

Tags: web-services

A company has developed a web service for us.  They have sent us the URL to the web service and the method and parameters we will need to call.  They said that they would send us the secure API key and they just did.  This key is in the format:  ABCDE_IBMPC_Z12345  but no other instructions.

My question is, they did not send any instructions on how to log in with this secure API key.  Is this something "generic" to all web services?  Can someone tell me how to use this key to authenticate and log in so that I can call the method I need to call?

Comment: No, it's not standard. They need to tell you.

Answer (score 0):

It will most likely need to be supplied as a querystring parameter... they should have told you what the parameter name is though :-)

It'll be something like ?api_key=ABCDE_IBMPC_Z12345

Comment: By this do you mean at the end of the method I'm using?  For example, if the method I'm eventually going to call is: GetData would I put it on the end of that?  Like:

webservice.GetData?api_key=ABCDE_IBMPC_Z12345

or should there be another method like "login"? as in:

webservice.login??api_key=ABCDE_IBMPC_Z12345

Comment: I'd expect the first approach, supplying the api key as part of the url for each request.  You'll only get the definitive answer from the company that wrote it for you though.